NestedIOException when configuring MyBatis via SqlSessionFactoryBean
I got an error when I try to config Mysql database with mybatis in spring :
Factory method 'sqlSessionFactoryBean' threw exception with message: org/springframework/core/NestedIOException
DbConfig.java :
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("sqlmapconfig.xml"));
    return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession(SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(), ExecutorType.BATCH);
}

application.properties :
spring.port=9090
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.application.name=cashier

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:thin:@128.0.0.1:3306:cashier
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mappers/*.xml

pom.xml
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <mybatis.version>3.5.16</mybatis.version>
    <mybatis.spring.version>3.0.3</mybatis.spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MyBatis dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis.spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I kinda lost here what should I configure or fix.
I've tried to search up and fix but none works.

As you are using spring-boot, you should use mybatis-spring-boot-starter. To new users, I recommend starting from a small working project and making small changes one by one. There is a skeleton project for mybatis-spring-boot-starter in this repo.
